# Issues with some words in google speech

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

I have a little issue with google speech.

I have an audio file in FLAC but when send that audio through google speech the response miss some words like yes, no, ok.

Someone happen the same.

I am using PHP 7.1 and the version Beta API:

This is my code:

$encoding = RecognitionConfig\AudioEncoding::FLAC;

$languageCode = 'en-US';

```
        $config = new RecognitionConfig();

        $speechContext = new SpeechContext(['phrases'=>array('yes', 'no','ok', ' okay')]);


        $config->setEncoding($encoding);
        $config->setEnableAutomaticPunctuation(true);
        $config->setEnableSpeakerDiarization(true);
        $config->setEnableSpeakerDiarization(3);
        $config->setSpeechContexts(array($speechContext));

        $config->setEnableWordTimeOffsets(true);
        $config->setLanguageCode($languageCode);
        $uri = $object->gcsUri();
        $audio = new RecognitionAudio();
        $audio->setUri($uri);
        $operationResponse = $speechClient->longRunningRecognize($config, $audio);
```

Thank

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce this error, one needs a copy of the audio file in question. You are encouraged to submit this audio file with a description of your issue in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/).